# PHP- combining two params within match() expression to be set dynamically

Tags: php, sorting, switch-statement, sql-order-by, preg-match

I am trying to set two parameters within my PHP project. One is `sortBy` and second is `orderBy`..

I am trying to define the best logic for it using [match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) expression, available from `PHP 8.0` version.

```
   $orderBy = $params['order'] ?? 'DESC';

   if (!preg_match('[ASC|DESC]', strtoupper($orderBy))) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Value for Order $orderBy allowed option ASC, DESC", 400);
    }

    $sortBy = match($params['sort']) {
        'createdAt' => 'user.created_at',
        'firstName' => 'user.first_name',
        'lastName'  => 'user.last_name',
        'username'  => 'user.username',
         default    => 'user.rank',
    };
```

My code works as expected as I first wanted to set default `DESC` but then figured out that will not be the best approach and I ran out of ides of how can I have `$params['order']` default to `DESC` in just two cases, on **createdAt** and **rank** and for others, logically, I want them on `ASC` but *STILL* to be able to set them dynamically.

I wanted to add another `match()` for **orderBy** but I guess I can maybe implement this logic in the already defined match so I do not need to write second one.

Does someone have better idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the default order that depends on the `sortBy` in another variable, and use that when setting `$orderBy`.

```
$defaultOrder = match($params['sort']) {
    'createdAt', 'rank' => 'DESC',
    default => 'ASC'
};

$orderBy = $params['order'] ?? $defaultOrder;
```

Comment: That's all I needed. Thanks! @Barmar